# Problema al prevenir duplicado con AJAX en SuiteCRM

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, sugarcrm

Buen dia a todos..
Estoy desarrollando una validación en SuiteCRM usando jQuery y Ajax, hice pruebas en otros módulos con el código y funciona normalmente.. al pasarlo a producción, el input al cual estoy apuntando "desaparece". No se trata de permisos y realmente ya no se por donde mirar el problema.

Dejo los pasos a continuación:

> > include/MVC/Controller/entry_point_registry.php
> > Cree un entry point el cual apunta a un archivo .php que hace una consulta sql, el cual  recibe como parámetro el input del campo "cuit_cuil_c" para validar su existencia..

> > custom/modules//
> > En esta carpeta fue creado el archivo .php.

Hasta acá, ok, fue testeado en producción este entry point con los parámetros correspondientes y se ejecuta de acuerdo a lo esperado.

> > custom/modules//views
> > Al no tener una vista de edición creada en modules//views, cree una clase en la carpeta CUSTOM/views (view.edit.php), la cual extiende de "EditView":

```
<?php

if (!defined('sugarEntry') || !sugarEntry) die('Not A Valid Entry Point');

class CustomEmpresasViewEdit extends ViewEdit
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();        
    }

    /**
     * @see SugarView::display()
     *
     * We are overridding the display method to manipulate the sectionPanels.
     * If portal is not enabled then don't show the Portal Information panel.
     */
    public function display()
    {     
        $this->useForSubpanel = true;
        
        // habilitamos el valor del nombre en el archivo tpl (enviar y recibir archivos por medio de HTTP)
        $this->ss->assign('cuit_cuil_c', $this->bean->cuit_cuil_c);

        // cargamos el contenido del tpl en la variable        
        $name_input_code = $this->ss->fetch('custom/modules/empre_Empresas_vp/tpls/cuitUnico.tpl.js');

        // enviamos el contenido a "editviewdefs"        
        $this->ss->assign('validacionCuit', $name_input_code);

            parent::display();
         
            
        }

        
    }

?>
```

Ok.. seguimos bien. La vista del módulo luego de aplicar este cambio sigue funcionando normalmente.

> > custom/modules//tpls/

```
<input type="text" name="cuit_cuil_c" id="cuit_cuil_c" maxlength="11" value="{$cuit_cuil_c}"/> 
<span id="cuit_unico_resultado"></span>

{literal}
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#cuit_cuil_c').blur(function(){
    
    $(".module-title-text").prop("id", "tipoVista");
        let vista = document.getElementById('tipoVista').innerHTML.trim();     
        $('#cuit_unico_resultado').html('<strong> Verificando cuit...</strong>');

        $.post('<http://rutaEntryPoint.php>', {cuit_cuil_c: $('#cuit_cuil_c').val()}, function(data){
        
        var cuitString = document.getElementById('cuit_cuil_c').value;
        var digitos = cuitString.length;
        const regex = /^[0-9]*$/;
        const soloNumeros = regex.test(cuitString);
           
           //Si existe la información o tiene menos de 11 dígitos, agregamos la propiedad Disabled al botón de guardar y le damos un valor true.
           //Agregamos comentarios para que el usuario sepa el motivo del error

        if(!soloNumeros){
            
                $(".button.primary").prop("disabled", "true");                               
                
                $('#cuit_unico_resultado').html('<strong style="color:red;"> &#x2717 <br>Ingrese únicamente dígitos numéricos</strong>');
            }       
    
            else if(digitos < 11){
            
                $(".button.primary").prop("disabled", "true");                               
                
                $('#cuit_unico_resultado').html('<strong style="color:red;"> &#x2717 <br>Debe tener al menos 11 dígitos</strong>');
            }            

            else if (data == 'existe' && vista=='Crear') {                
                          
                $(".button.primary").prop("disabled", "true");                               
                
                $('#cuit_unico_resultado').html('<strong style="color:red;"> &#x2717 <br>CUIT Duplicado o inválido</strong>');
            }
            else if (data == 'existe' && vista != 'Crear' || data == 'unico') {                
               
                $(".button.primary").prop("disabled", "")

                $('#cuit_unico_resultado').html('<strong style="color:green;"> &#x2713 </strong>');
            }
            else {}

        });
    })
});
</script>
{/literal}
```

El script realiza validaciones varias con fin de que el usuario no pueda avanzar en caso de no cumplir las condiciones.

..Por ahora no va a tener ningun efecto, ya que en la carpeta <custom/modules//metadata/editviewdefs.php> no modificamos el comportamiento del campo.. vamos a eso

> > custom/modules//metadata/editviewdefs.php

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'name' => 'cuit_cuil_c',
    'label' => 'LBL_CUIT_CUIL',
'customCode' => '{$validacionCuit}',
  ),
```

Al momento de guardar y hacer una "Reparación rápida" del suiteCRM, el input del campo 'cuit_cuil_c' desaparece de la vista.

No encuentro ya la manera de avanzar con esto, ya que no veo diferencias entre las pruebas realizadas en el local y test.

Agradezco su ayuda.